# Conditional Merge with nested Rank in Pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I’m trying to translate a conditional merge with nested rank from SQL to Python-Pandas.
Specifically, I would like to merge two tables and add a condition, which ensures a 1:1 relationship and specifies which value to take. 
In SQL this would be implemented by a subquery with Ranks which is one-sided joined with a condition.

**Example**

I merge the customer records table with a table of customer requests.
The result should show the latest record before or at the time of its own timestamp.

```
table: Customer_records
+---------+------+------------+
| Cust_ID | Name | Timestamp  |
+---------+------+------------+
|       1 | A    | 2013-01-01 |
|       1 | A    | 2014-01-01 |
|       1 | A    | 2015-12-01 |
|       2 | B    | 2014-01-01 |
|       3 | C    | 2014-01-01 |
+---------+------+------------+

table: customer_request
+--------+---------+------------+
| Req_ID | Cust_ID | Timestamp  |
+--------+---------+------------+
|      1 |       1 | 2013-01-01 |
|      2 |       1 | 2013-12-01 |
|      3 |       1 | 2015-01-01 |
|      4 |       2 | 2013-01-01 |
+--------+---------+------------+

table: merged
+---------+------+------------+--------+
| Cust_ID | Name | Timestamp  | Req_ID |
+---------+------+------------+--------+
|       1 | A    | 2013-01-01 | 1      |
|       1 | A    | 2014-01-01 | 2      |
|       1 | A    | 2015-12-01 | 3      |
|       2 | B    | 2014-01-01 | 4      |
|       3 | C    | 2014-01-01 | None   |
+---------+------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), only necessary sorting both `DataFrame`s by `Timestamp` columns:

```
Customer_records['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Customer_records['Timestamp'])
customer_request['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_request['Timestamp'])

Customer_records = Customer_records.sort_values('Timestamp')
customer_request = customer_request.sort_values('Timestamp')

df = pd.merge_asof(Customer_records, customer_request, on='Timestamp', by='Cust_ID')
   Cust_ID Name  Timestamp  Req_ID
0        1    A 2013-01-01     1.0
1        1    A 2014-01-01     2.0
2        2    B 2014-01-01     4.0
3        3    C 2014-01-01     NaN
4        1    A 2015-12-01     3.0
```

Comment: This is super helpful. However it is specific to the case of a 1:1 matching scenario. I was asking for a general translation of ranking in conditional joining to be able to translate SQL code into pandas for more sophisticated queries; for example, where the two latest values (rank <=2) is always taken.